# Is there a "noreturn" keyword in Java

Tags: java, compiler-construction, return

Sometimes I want to write a error() function which will surely call System.exit() in the end, meaning that this function will never return. However, if I call error() in other functions, I want to write like:

```
int fun() {
...
  error();
}
```

But the compiler insist on returning a int value after the error() call since it don't know that error() will never return.
I can surely return a arbitrary int, but if the return type is a complex class, I need to construct it in the code which is a waste of time. Is there any way to tell the compiler that a function will never return?

Comment: The answer to your question is "no".  A quick check of the Java language manual shows that.  Why ask?  More importantly, why not throw an exception instead of calling `System.exit()`?

Answer (score 6):

There is no way in a Java method signature that you can tell the compiler that the method cannot return.  Without that, the compiler has no option but to assume that it might return.  (Indeed, the JLS rules about reachability / definite assignment will state this explicitly ... if you care to wade through them.)

I vacillate between two approaches:

```
int fun() {
    ...
    error();
    return 0;  // NOT REACHED
}
```

and

```
int fun() {
    ...
    error();
    throw new AssertionError("not reached");
}
```

Neither is entirely satisfactory.

In the first version, the comment is important, since someone reading your code for the first time might not realize that `error` never returns.

The second version is more robust, since it will give you a "fast fail" if someone changes the behaviour of the `error` method so that it actually returns.  (The first version will result in the the `fun` method returning a bogus value ... possibly leading to other unintended consequences.)

---

On a related point, a method that pulls the plug on the JVM by calling `System.exit()` can be problematic.  A better idea is to throw an unchecked "end the world" exception and catch it at the outermost level of your main thread.  For exceptions thrown on other threads, one idea would be to install a default uncaught exception handler that uses `Thread.interrupt()` to notify the main thread that an "end the world" exception has been thrown.

But the point is that `System.exit()` calls made deep down in the code are problematic; e.g. if you repurpose your code to run within a larger framework; e.g. in a web container.

Comment: I don't get why doesn't java have noreturn method type similar to void...

Comment: It was a design decision.  Either they complicate the language by providing special syntax to support this edge-case, and people complain about the extra complexity.  Or they don't and (different) people complain that the edge-case is not well supported.  They had to make a decision.  They can't please everyone.

Answer (score 5):

You should throw a [RuntimeException](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/RuntimeException.html).

Comment: or even subclass it to create a NotPossibleException, that way if it gets thrown you know for sure something is seriously wrong, and the code is clearer.

Comment: @mathepic, if the OP throws a `RuntimeException` exception **instead** of calling `System.exit()` (as should be the case) then it will in fact certainly be possible for the exception to be thrown.

Comment: Nevermind, I misread your suggestion, I suppose. I thought you meant error then RuntimeException to stop the compiler from complaining/

Answer (score 4):

Java does not allow you to declare that your *method* never returns, but the compiler knows a *statement* that never returns: `throw`.

You can exploit that in your situation by declaring your "no-return" method to return a `RuntimeException`, and call it using `throw error()`.  This way you shift the problem of a "method that does not return" to a "statement that does not return".

Since your `error()` method never returns, you don't need to actually return the declared `RuntimeException`, and the `throw` in `throw error()` is never executed.

This technique can also prevent you from bugs when `error()` does return, maybe because of some buggy conditional code.

Example:

```
private RuntimeException error() {
    throw new EndOfTheWorldException();
    // Java knows that code after throw will not be reached
    // so no return is required here.  Or, if you insist, you
    // could call System.exit() and return null afterwards.
}

int fun() {
    // ...
    throw error();
    // Again, no need for a return here, the compiler understands
    // that the statement above won't return.
}
```

Alternatively, and maybe more explicitly, you could refactor this code to make `error()` a factory for the exception to be thrown:

```
private RuntimeException makeError() {
    return new EndOfTheWorldException();
}

int fun() {
    throw makeError();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

return 0, or in complex cases, return null.

Comment: If the return type is an int, you cannot return null as they are incompatible types.

Comment: Yea, then return 0, OR in complex cases, return null;

Comment: -1 for the 'return null', since the specific question was about return type int (and for the comment you added afterward to your own answer).

Comment: @Ken, if you read the question carefully, you would have noticed: "I can surely return a arbitrary int, but if the return type is a complex class, I need to construct it in the code which is a waste of time". As for "adding afterward" to answer, Gnostus' answer was not edited since he has written it ...

Comment: Retracting downvote. I misread the question. As far as the remark I made about the comment, it's the second **comment** in this very thread (about four above this one) to which I was referring; Gnostus simply repeated the initial answer, preceded by "Yea, then". My comment making that point should probably also be deleted, as it was inappropriate; leaving it for context to the rest of the comments that follow, though, including my admission of my mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you want to do this. It'd be cleaner code, more testable and maintainable, if you threw an exception; you could use `Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler()` to exit.

But if you insist:

```
public class HaltAndCatchFireError extends Error {
   public HaltAndCatchFireError() {
      System.exit(1);
   }
}
```

And then where you want to exit:

```
int fun() {
   ...
   throw new HaltAndCatchFireError();
}
```

Comment: I'd call this a bad idea.  1) It looks like you are throwing an exception.  2) If you really did execute that constructor, something really bad would happen.

Comment: @Stephen Oh, absolutely. But interspersing System.exit() randomly around your code is *already* a bad idea. :)

Answer (score 0):

Does your function ever return anything?  If not you want your function to be void, it seems:

```
void fun() {

...


}
```

Answer (score -2):

You can write

```
error();
return;
```

But you may reconsider your approach. This may not be a very object oriented one.

Comment: It really doesn't have anything to do with object-orientedness.  This is a syntax/semantics issue.  Is it legal Java, to not return anything when you're supposed to return an int, even though you're never really "returning" at all?  Generally not, which is the reason for the question.

Comment: You're trying to broke the api's contract (that is: return int or throw exception). the better approach would be throw `RuntimeException`.

Comment: that is terrible answer plus throwing random runtime exceptions are bad, this is semantically dead code anyways